# How can display data coming from database inside textview

Tags: android, database

I have one fragment, retrieve name title from another fragment, and must be show details in this fragment. But I can't display data inside Textview.

this is my **HistoryFragment**

```
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String TAG = "HISTORY_COUNTRY";
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
public static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
public int countryIDs;
ArrayList<AsiaCountry> asiaList = new ArrayList<>();
AsiaCountry asiaCountry;
int position;
Bundle bundle;
String content;
private List<AsiaCountry> item = Collections.emptyList();
private TextView historyContent;
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private HistoryOnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public HistoryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);


    bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        content = bundle.getString("name");
        Log.d("content", content.toString());
    }
    fetchData();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);

     historyContent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);



    historyContent.setText(asiaCountry.getHistory());
    Log.d("His", historyContent.getText().toString());

    return view;
}

private void fetchData() {
    WorldCountry worldCountry = new WorldCountry(getActivity());

    worldCountry.checkCopyDatabase();
    worldCountry.openDataBase();
    Log.d(ARG_PARAM1, "Database opened");

    try {

        Cursor cursor = worldCountry.QueryData("SELECT history FROM country WHERE name = ?" + content);
        Log.d("CURSOR", cursor.toString());

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    AsiaCountry asia = new AsiaCountry();
                    asia.setHistory(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("history")));
                    Log.d(ARG_PARAM2, cursor.getString(0));
                    asiaList.add(asia);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                worldCountry.close();
            }

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("TAG", e.getMessage());

    }


}


// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.historyOnFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof HistoryOnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (HistoryOnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}


public interface HistoryOnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void historyOnFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

In above code, I retrieve data from database, and I want display in Textview, But I can't.

Guys I think my duery is wrong, because I don't retrieve history column and for this reason, asiaList don't add asia.setHistory(cursor.getString(0)); maybe I'm wrong. I must tell to cursor retrieve history column where name = content.

Comment: Please provide log if any error is coming in the code.
NullPointer will  come when you  call asiaCountry.getHistory(), because asiaCountry is not initialized.

Comment: What does not work? Retrieving data from the database or displaying the data in a textview?

Comment: @anddevmanu Hi dear. I retrieve content from another fragment, But I try to debugging  asiaList.add(asia); , for know , do add history or not . But I can't see this break point, message variables are not available appear.

Comment: @Denny I can't display data in Textview. I think for this reason, asiaList don't add asia.setHistory, and when use   historyContent.setText(asiaCountry.getHistory()); , historyContent nothing happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
if(asiaList != null && asiaList.size()>0){
  for(int i=0;i<asiaList.size();i++){
     historyContent.append(asiaList.get(i).getHistory()+"\n");
  }
}
```

instead of

```
historyContent.setText(asiaCountry.getHistory());
```

try this in your query

```
Cursor cursor = worldCountry.QueryData("SELECT history FROM country WHERE name = '"+content+"'");
```

Comment: Thanks so much dear . But nothing happen when use above code in my project, Because my asiaList don't add asia.setHistory. I confused , when retrieve content from another fragment, and tell to the cursor , select history column who are = with content, But don't getString from database.

Comment: are you debug fetchData method in your project?

Comment: Yes dear I did. But line " asiaList.add(asia) and asia.setHistory disabled . I think my duery  is  wrong , because of this I can't retrieve history column and setHistory.

Comment: your query like : Cursor cursor = worldCountry.QueryData("SELECT history FROM country WHERE name = '"+content+"'");

Comment: can you put your QueryData method here?

Comment: this is my Query dear.     Cursor cursor = worldCountry.QueryData("SELECT history FROM country WHERE name = ?" + content);

Comment: Ok dera, I try and comment here, Thanks so ,much.

Comment: error illegal appear inside " ' + content + " ' " . Please note exact and separate end of  Query.

Comment: Thanks dear . Thanks so much. query is worked. I am so glad for you'r help and other friends, Thanks dear :).

Comment: Glad it worked.Please accept my answer.You can also visit : https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get more information about SO and support me as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

there is no content in asiaCountry.

```
  historyContent.setText(asiaCountry.getHistory());
```

Try to get content from list by giving desired position. for ex.

```
     historyContent.setText(asiaList.get(0).getHistory);
```

Comment: Thanks dear for respond, But error appear say : size is 0. and this is for when I add asia to asiaList. asiaList is empty. I confused.